# How to set QToolButton fill in the side bar(QDockWidget) in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, sidebar, qdockwidget, qtoolbutton

I wrote a minimal example which has a sidebar which contains a `QToolButton` on it. I set `setAutoRaise(true)` for the `QToolButton`, so when hover on it, the button will raise. But currently I have a minor issue. As you can see from the picture below, when hover on the button, the border on the right and left are not fully take the whole screen. 
Here is how that looks like:
[image]

And this example what I want to button to look like:
[image]

And here is my code:

```
sidebarDock = new QDockWidget(this);
addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, sidebarDock);

//hide dock widget title bar
QWidget *titleBarWidget = new QWidget(sidebarDock);
sidebarDock->setTitleBarWidget(titleBarWidget);
sidebarDock->titleBarWidget()->hide();

dockWidget = new QWidget(sidebarDock);
dockWidget->setObjectName("DockWidget");
dockWidget->setStyleSheet("#DockWidget { background-color: #F7DC6F; }");
dockVLayout = new QVBoxLayout(dockWidget);
overviewBtn = new QToolButton(dockWidget);
overviewBtn->setAutoRaise(true);
overviewBtn->setIcon(QIcon(":/Icons/overview.png"));
overviewBtn->setText("Overview");
overviewBtn->setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonTextUnderIcon);
dockVLayout->addWidget(overviewBtn);
dockWidget->setLayout(dockVLayout);
sidebarDock->setWidget(dockWidget);
```

So can someone tell me which part I missed to set the `QQToolButton` right and left border completely to side? Or are there some better ways to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you need to 1. Remove margins, 2. Create bigger image

Comment: @Serhiy 1. I tried to set both button and layout margin to 0 with `setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)`, it still remains the same; 2. I tried using a bigger image, but the margin is still there. Are there some other ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I solved this problem.
Just need to add one line to the code snippet to set the layout's margin to 0, using: `dockVLayout->setMargin(0)`